# I got error (root) Additional property django is not allowed , when run django in pycharm

Tags: django, docker-compose, pycharm

I got this error since this morning.

`(root) Additional property django is not allowed`

I didn't change my code since last night. The error has occured today.

It seems cause by `docker-compse.yaml` . This is my `yaml` file.

```
version: "3"

services:

  django:
    container_name: image_maker
    image: image_maker:latest
    volumes:
      - .:/docker
      - ./log:/tmp/
    ports:
      - 8003:8080
    working_dir: /docker/app
    environment:
      - DEBUG=True
      - LOCAL_DB=True
    networks:
      - my_network
networks:
  my_network:
    external: true
```

I didn't changed it a few days. And also I run another django project. It has same error.

`(root) Additional property *** is not allowed`

So I checked my all project. It got same error.

I thins this is not yaml file error. It is interpreter error on Pycharm. When I open `Configure Remote Python interpreter`, Service can select `network` and `service`. This is strange. The dropdown should be `django`.

[image]

I don't no why the dropdown can't show correct services. I restarted Pycharm and my Mac.

However this problem still beeing. Please help me.

- Pycharm 2021.1.1
- MacOS 11.5.2
- Docker Desktop Version 4.0.0 (4.0.0.12)
- Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this error by this 3 steps.

1. Download latest version of PyCharm from [website](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=mac)
2. Replace old version in Application folder.
3. Start latest version of PyCharm.

[image]
[image]